# Weibull Parameter Estimation

Tags: estimation, censoring, weibull-distribution, parameterization

I am doing a project in which I need to estimate Weibull parameters for car part failures (I know the data follow Weibull). I have data for 1000 cars (part failure data). Now the problem is suppose some part fails after 6 years (from date of manufacturing) . But I have data for only the first three years. Now in three years this particular part may have failed in only a very few cars. Since I am taking miles driven as cycle to estimate parameters, very few will be less than some threshold. So when I estimate parameters based on that sample, it gives me wrong results. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: It sounds like a good part of your data is right-censored. Look up survival analysis and right-censoring. A maximum likelihood approach might work for you here.

Answer (score 1):

@soakley already gave you the main keyword - survival analysis - so I'll just mention that a good solution is either R's classic `survival` package [(this function)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survreg.html), or `flexsurv`, which has more flexibility, but a different parametrization for Weibull (`flexsurvreg` function [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/flexsurv.pdf)).